# Soft question regarding sequence of functions.

Tags: measure-theory

Studying measure theory, I see sequences of functions of the style :  $ f_n(x) = \frac{1}{n} \Bbb{1}_{[0,n]} $

Now, my trouble in understanding this is that the variable “x” has disappeared. Are these sequences of functions just straight lines for each $f_1,f_2,…$?

Sorry if the question is too silly.

Comment: It's written poorly.  There should either be an $x$ on both sides or none at all.

Comment: The $x$ on one side is essential to OP's question and should not be edited out.

Comment: By definition, $1_{[0,n]}$ is

$$1_{[0,n]} = \begin{cases}1 \text{ if } x\in[0,n] \\ 0 \text{ if } x\notin[0,n] \end{cases}$$

So the function does depend on $x$, it's just hidden.

Comment: @DanielP That is the point. Are $f_1, f_2, …$ straight lines?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, what you've been seeing is a typo of some sort, or a strange convention I've never seen. More conventionally you would have either
$$
f_n = \frac 1 n 1_{[0,n]}
\qquad
f_n(x) = \frac 1 n 1_{[0,n]}(x)
$$
i.e. either both sides have the variable, or neither do. A variable certainly must be involved because, when these functions come up, they are not constant functions, as
$$
f_n(x) = \frac 1 n 1_{[0,n]}(x)
= \begin{cases}
1/n, & x \in [0,n] \\
0, & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
These functions are useful in part because their integrals are "obviously" $1$. You can see their intended graphs in [this Desmos demo](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/az3idixezh).

Comment: Is each $f_k$ a straing line?

Comment: Have you looked at the Desmos graph? Each $f_n$ is a combination of three flat line segments - $x = \frac{1}{n}$ on the interval $[0, n]$, and $x= 0$ to the left and right of it.

Comment: @ConMan Now I see it clearly. Thanks.